# Разница между const и constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, const

В чём разница между `const int x` и `constexpr int x`? Что из этого стоит использовать?

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const#14117121

Comment: В каком контексте?

Comment: @alexolut вообще

Comment: писал об этом [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/11/19/constant_expressions.aspx) — можете почитать.

Comment: @ixSci спасибо!

Comment: @GreenDragon Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-2000-3.html в ней хорошо описана разница

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Самый простой пример. Данная программа компилируется

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    constexpr static double x = 10.0;
};


int main() 
{
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

А данная программа нет.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    const static double x = 10.0;
};


int main() 
{
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

Существенное значение также имеет место, когда этот спецификатор, `constexpr`, используется для функций.

Как вы знаете, только функции-члены класса могут иметь квалификатор `const`, который имеет отношение к объекту, для которого вызывается данная функция-член класса.

Обычные функции не могут быть константными.

Спецификатор `constexpr` введен для того, чтобы заставить компилятор на этапе кмпиляции создавать объекты и использовать их как константы времени компиляции.

Например, известно, что стандарт C++ для задания размерности массива требует константное выражение. Используя спецификатор `constexpr` вы можете задавать размер массива, используя некоторые функции. Например,

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    constexpr A( bool b ) : n( b ? 5 : 10 ) {}
    size_t n;
};


int main() 
{
    int a[A( true ).n];
    int b[A( false ).n];

    int i = 0;
    for ( int &x : a ) x = i++;

    i = 0;
    for ( int &x : b ) x = i++;

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : b ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Использование `constexpr` позволяет заниматься метапрограммированием на этапе компиляции, как альтернативная возможность для шаблонного метапрограммирования.

Answer (score 16):

`const int x` - переменная `x` не должна меняться в процессе работы программы, а `constexpr int x` - оно еще и должна получить свое значение во время компиляции...

Например,

```
int n;
cin >> n;
const int x = n*n;
```

Отработает, x получит свое значение, которое нельзя будет менять - но получит во время работы программы.

Если написать `constexpr` - не скомпилируется, ибо во время компиляции `x` не известно.

Соответственно этому - используйте то, что более подходит для ваших целей. Где можно - лучше `constexpr`, где нет - просто `const`.